# Oracle Warning in Alert Log Regarding PGA_AGGREGATE_LIMIT

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, configuration

### Introduction

During the startup process of our Oracle instances, we are encountering the following error message in the alert log:

> ```
> WARNING: pga_aggregate_limit value is too high for the
> amount of physical memory on the system
>   PGA_AGGREGATE_LIMIT is 2048 MB
>   PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET is 256 MB.
>   physical memory size is 0 MB
>   limit based on physical memory and SGA usage is 512 MB
>   SGA_TARGET is 6144 MB
> Using default pga_aggregate_limit of 2048 MB
> ```

#### Physical RAM

What is strange is the fact that the `physical memory size` in the WARNING is being displayed as `0 MB`, because our physical server has 768 GB of physical RAM. (Yes, the server isn't a virtual server; physical only for Oracle.)

#### Spfile and Pfile Configuration

The `SGA_TARGET` and `SGA_MAX_TARGET` parameters in the `pfile_SID.ora` and `spfile_SID.ora` have been configured at `6144M`. Here a list of the interesting parameters from the PFILE:

```
...
processes              = 500
...
memory_max_target      = 0
memory_target          = 0
sga_max_size           = 6144M
sga_target             = 6144M
...
pga_aggregate_target   = 256M
...
```

#### Documentation for PGA_AGGREGATE_LIMIT

According to the Oracle documentation for [`PGA_AGGREGATE_LIMIT`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-E364D0E5-19F2-4081-B55E-131DF09CFDB3.htm#REFRN10328) the value will be set according to the following rules:

> By default, `PGA_AGGREGATE_LIMIT` is set to the greater of...
>
> - 2 GB,
> - 200% of `PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET`,
> - and 3 MB times the `PROCESSES` parameter.
>
> It will be set below 200% of `PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET` if it is larger than 90% of the physical memory size minus the total SGA size, but not below 100% of `PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET`.

<sup>**(Important bit at the end regarding restrictions)**</sup>

#### Oracle Patch Level

The current patch level of the server is:

> ```
> Patch Id: 26758841
> Patch Description: WINDOWS DB BUNDLE PATCH 12.2.0.1.171017(64bit):26758841
> ```

---

### Applying Documentation to Oracle Configuration

Because we haven't manually configured the `PGA_AGGREGATE_LIMIT` parameter Oracle is going to be so nice and do that for us. This means Oracle is going to set the value to the greater of the following values:

- 2 GB
- 200% of `PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET` = 200% * 256 MB = 512 MB
- 3 MB times `PROCESSES` = 3 MB * 500 = 1.5 GB

**...but** there would be the restriction cited above, which in my case would mean:

> ```
> 90% * Physical Memory - 6144 MB = 90% * 0 MB - 6144 MB = <0 MB
> ```

Ok. Because Oracle is listing the server's physical RAM as `0 MB` we are going to hit the restriction and Oracle should throttle the `PGA_AGGREGATE_LIMIT` value to `256 MB`.

But Oracle is setting the value to `2048 MB`!

---

### Questions

1. Why is the physical RAM being listed as `0 MB`?
2. Why is Oracle setting the `PGA_AGGREGATE_LIMIT` to `2048 MB` instead of `256 MB`?
3. Can I safely ignore the warning?

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question?.

Comment: Mike Dietrich wrote: [In all cases, the default PGA_AGGREGATE_LIMIT is at least 2GB and at least 3MB times the PROCESSES parameter.”](https://mikedietrichde.com/2017/05/04/pga_aggregate_limit-enforces-default-since-oracle-database-12-2-0-1/)

Comment: @miracle173 No. I have not found an answer to my question. _Yet_.

Comment: @miracle173 Woudl you like to post your comment + some prose as an answer? I think this might benefit the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to a blog post by [Mike Dietrich](https://mikedietrichde.com/2017/05/04/pga_aggregate_limit-enforces-default-since-oracle-database-12-2-0-1/):

> In Oracle Database 12.2.0.1 the default value gets adjusted a bit as it turned out that restricting PGA_AGGREGATE_LIMIT to a value too low will lead to a significant number of issues.
>
> See the Oracle Database 12.2.0.1 documentation on PGA_AGGREGATE_LIMIT explaining:
>
> > If MEMORY_TARGET is set, then PGA_AGGREGATE_LIMIT defaults to the MEMORY_MAX_TARGET value.
> >
> > If MEMORY_TARGET is not set, then PGA_AGGREGATE_LIMIT defaults to 200% of PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET.
> >
> > If MEMORY_TARGET is not set, and PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET is explicitly set to 0, then the value of PGA_AGGREGATE_LIMIT is set to 90% of the physical memory size minus the total SGA size.
> >
> > In all cases, the default PGA_AGGREGATE_LIMIT is at least 2GB and at least 3MB times the PROCESSES parameter.
>
> And please remember, DO NOT use MEMORY_TARGET as it will lead to issues such as no use of huge pages etc.

So the solution is to manually set the `PGA_AGGREGATE_LIMIT` parameter to a value twice the size of `PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET`. Because in our case this value is 500 (processes) x  3 MB = 1.5 GB, we had to set the value of `PGA_AGGREGATE_LIMIT` to **3 GB**.

Answer (score 1):

According to our database admins, this is a known ORACLE error since version 12. We have been advised to set *pga_aggregate_limit* to *0* in order to work around this problem. I haven't been able to test this thoroughly, but we haven't seen errors since changing this setting (using *alter system*, we haven't set the parameter in our database's [s]pfile).